TypeError: newCollection[Symbol.iterator] is not a function @for Angular 17
here is my code, error happens in the @for line
<div>
        <ul>
            @for (paragraph of paragraphs; track paragraph) {
            <li>{{ paragraph }}</li>
            }
            @empty {
            <li>No items found</li>
            }
          </ul>
    </div>

Here is my service
paragraphs = {} as string[];

onInputUrlReturnParagraph(url: string) {
this.helloService.getPragraphsFromScraper(url).subscribe(
(paragraphs) => {
  this.paragraphs = paragraphs.split(" {Joined Point} ");
}
)

}
This is the error im getting
TypeError: newCollection[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
at reconcile (core.mjs:22571:68)
at Module.ɵɵrepeater (core.mjs:22933:9)
at HelloComponent_Template (hello.component.html:34:17)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11268:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:12791:13)
at detectChangesInView$1 (core.mjs:13015:9)
at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (core.mjs:12978:5)
at detectChangesInComponent (core.mjs:12967:5)
at detectChangesInChildComponents (core.mjs:13028:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:12841:13)

anybody face this issue? Thank you!

in declaration: why paragraphs = {} as string[];? can you explain this?

It might be kind of dumb, but I couldn't figure out how to return a raw List of integers so I joined them with a breakpoint "Joined Point" and broke them up into the string[].

paragraphs should be an array, not {}.
getPragraphsFromScraper() is asynchronous, so paragraphs will be evaluated  before the observable sends a new value.

For me I got this error when the return type of an http call was not as I expected it (I expected a list, it turned out to be a page). This, however manifested only at the level of my iteration in the HTML template (typescript is not THAT strictly typed, you know).
To me it seems that your case should be similar: it seems you are making HTTP call in this service. Obviously, this is a speculation, but since I answer with 4 months of delay, I just type this here, for future reference if anyone in the future encounters similar situation.
I would suggest that you make sure the service call returns objects of the type you expect.
